# Joining 2 array of objects into 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays :

```
var arr1 = [ { id: 137, surname: 'Smith', name: 'John', avg: 14.5 }];

var arr2 = [{ subject: 'Maths', code: 'IPSE507'} ];
```

I want to join them so that I have

```
var arr3 = [ { id: 137, surname: 'Smith', name: 'John', avg: 14.5, subject: 'Maths', code: 'IPSE507'} ];
```

But when I do `Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2)` I get :

```
var arr3 = [ { id: 137, surname: 'Smith', name: 'John', avg: 5.5 }, { subject: 'Maths', code: 'IPSE507' } ];
```

How to get rid of the curly braces in the middle so that it will be one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**Array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over them. After that just use [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function to assign appropriate properties.

Be aware, that it takes objects using **index**

```js
var arr1 = [ { id: 137, surname: 'Smith', name: 'John', avg: 14.5 }];

var arr2 = [{ subject: 'Maths', code: 'IPSE507'} ];

var newArr = arr1.map((item, index) => (Object.assign({},item, arr2[index])));

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: while this works, it mutates the original object. so either take an empty object as target for `Object.assign`, or skip the map part, because you mutate `arr1`. btw, `Object.assign` needs no outer parenthesis.

Comment: That did it, thanks! But is there another way of writing it? Webstorm underlines red the arrow and the final parenthesis

Comment: Nevermind, found it, it's :  `arr1.map(function(item, index){
                        Object.assign(item, arr2[index]);
                    });`

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks